# Converting a 1D list to a 2D table

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

A few days ago someone asked this question. But they quickly deleted the post offering no solution.
Given:

```py
a = ['COP' , '\t\t\t', 'Basis', 'Notl', 'dv01', '6m', '9m', '1y',
     '18m', '2y', '3y', "15.6", 'mm', '4.6', '4y', '5y', '10', 'mm',
     '4.6', '6y', '7y', '8y', '9y', '10y', '20y', 'TOTAL', '\t\t9.2' ]
```

They needed to traverse the list and get the following 2D table.
Where the first column has only values ending in "m" or "y".

```py
"COB", "Basis", "Notl"
('6m', '', '')
('9m', '', '')
('1y', '', '')
('18m', '', '')
('2y', '', '')
('3y', '15.6', '')
('4y', '', '')
('5y', '10', '')
('6y', '', '')
('7y', '', '')
('8y', '', '')
('9y', '', '')
('10y', '', '')
('20y', '', '')
```

I answered the question,  using a coroutine and a linked list as shown below:

```
a = ['COP' , '\t\t\t', 'Basis', 'Notl', 'dv01', '6m', '9m', '1y',
     '18m', '2y', '3y', "15.6", 'mm', '4.6', '4y', '5y', '10', 'mm',
     '4.6', '6y', '7y', '8y', '9y', '10y', '20y', 'TOTAL', '\t\t9.2' ]

headers = ('COP', "Basis", 'Notl', 'dv01')


def is_Number(value):
    is_number = False
    try:
        float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        is_number = True
    return is_number


def is_cob(value):
    return True if (value[0].isnumeric() and (value[-1] == "m" or value[-1] == "y")) \
        else False


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_cop=None, next_column=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_cop = None
        self.next_column = None



class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headNode = None

    def printlist(self):
        print("This is the list =>:")
        temp = self.headNode
        while temp:
            print("Data-> :", temp.data)
            temp1 = temp.next_column
            while temp1:
                print("|")
                print("--->Column: Bias, Notl =", temp1.data)
                temp1 = temp1.next_column
            temp = temp.next_cop

    def isEmpty(self):
        return False if self.headNode else True

    def insert_at_head(self, node):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.headNode = node
        else:
            node.next_cop = self.headNode
            self.headNode = node

    def insert_at_tail(self, node):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.headNode = node
            return
        temp = self.headNode
        while temp.next_cop:
            temp = temp.next_cop
        temp.next_cop = node

    def insert_at_tail_column_of_nodeX(self, nodeX, node):
        temp = self.get_pointer_to_nodeX(nodeX)
        while temp.next_column:
            temp = temp.next_column
        temp.next_column = node

    def get_pointer_to_nodeX(self, nodeX):
        temp = self.headNode
        while temp.next_cop != nodeX:
            temp = temp.next_cop
        temp = temp.next_cop
        return temp

    def get_last_node_data(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return self.headNode.data
        temp = self.headNode
        while temp.next_cop:
            temp = temp.next_cop
        return temp.data

    def get_last_node(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return self.headNode
        temp = self.headNode
        while temp.next_cop:
            temp = temp.next_cop
        return temp

    def iterate_from(self, node=None):
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next_cop


def rows(llist):
    lst = []
    while True:
        value = yield
        if value is None:
            break
        lst.append(value)
        is_number = is_Number(value)
        if is_cob(value):
            llist.insert_at_tail(Node(value))
        if is_number and is_cob(llist.get_last_node_data()) \
                and (is_cob(lst[-2]) or is_Number(lst[-2])):
            llist.insert_at_tail_column_of_nodeX(llist.get_last_node(), Node(value))
    return llist


if __name__ == "__main__":
    llist = LinkedList()

    sent_to_coro = [elem for elem in a if elem not in headers]
    coro_rows = rows(llist)
    next(coro_rows)
    for element in sent_to_coro:
        print("Sending....", element)
        coro_rows.send(element)
    try:
        coro_rows.send(None)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        result = exc.value

    out = []
    for item in llist.iterate_from(llist.headNode):
        cop = item.data
        basis = item.next_column.data if item.next_column else ""
        notl = item.next_column.next_column.data if basis and item.next_column.next_column else ""
        out.append((cop,basis,notl))
    for itm in out:
        print(itm)
```

Someone posted a solution with regex that was just a few lines of code, but unfortunately it was deleted because the question itself was just a question with no code and immediately started to be downvoted of course.

I would like to:

1. Hear some suggestion on this code. Specifically, I wanted to know
   if there is any real improvement to this code.
2. Is this solution overworked?
3. I would like to see other solutions to this problem using Regex

Comment: Do you have a link to the original post. Even though it is deleted?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It was all so fast, I  just can tell it was a couple of days ago and it was his/her first post in https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Let me clarify, that I answered the question but was not even able to post it. What I'm looking for is a review of my response and the answer that was posted that was using RegEx

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I guess it is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940421/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-this-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I found a solution using RegEx that indeed shows what I did is overworked. I failed to see the array as a long string and apply a RegEx to it

```py
import re
a = ['COP' , '\t\t\t', 'Basis', 'Notl', 'dv01', '6m', '9m', '1y',
     '18m', '2y', '3y', "15.6", 'mm', '4.6', '4y', '5y', '10', 'mm',
     '4.6', '6y', '7y', '8y', '9y', '10y', '20y', 'TOTAL', '\t\t9.2']

   rule2 = re.compile(r"\b(\d+[ym])\W+([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)*\b")
    a_str = " ".join(a)
    OUT2 = re.findall(rule2, a_str)
    print(OUT2)
```

output

```
>> [('6m', ''), ('9m', ''), ('1y', ''), ('18m', ''), ('2y', ''), ('3y', '15.6'), ('4y', ''), ('5y', '10'), ('6y', ''), ('7y', ''), ('8y', ''), ('9y', ''), ('10y', ''), ('20y', '')]
```

Answer (score 2):

To be brief on your three points.

You can try to omit extra variables and trust the function boundary.  For example, your code starts with this excellently named function:

```
def is_Number(value):
    is_number = False
    try:
        float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        is_number = True
    return is_number
```

or more concisely,

```
def is_Number(value):
   try:
      float(value)
   except ValueError:
      return False
   return True
```

You might see [Code Like A Pythonista](http://www.omahapython.org/IdiomaticPython.html) for a better explanation.

Yes, your code does seem overly worked for the problem.

Instead of giving you a regex, I recommend [Regex101](http://regex101.com).  It is a single web page playground for experimenting with RegEx with full explanations of what matches.  Be sure to pick 'Python' for the dialect.

Keep hacking!  Keep notes.